# Modal UITableViewController (static cells) with toolbar

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, toolbar

What I would like is a modal `UITableViewController` with a toolbar at the bottom. The end goal is selecting certain rows as the 'active' rows (for filtering search results) and then hitting 'done' in the toolbar to finish the search. The kind of toolbar I'm looking for is like this:

[image]

I've searched and searched over SO however my combination is slightly different, it appears (ignore the empty row, this has a purpose later on)

[image]

You can't do `self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;` because that's for a 'push' rather than 'modal'.

Alternatively this pattern may be frowned upon and an alternate suggestion could be made as to how this kind of filtering should really be done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is a bit premature after spending roughly 4-5 hours seeing how this should be done.

The answer is to select your view controller in the storyboard, hit 'Editor' > 'Embed In' > 'Navigation Controller'. It opens a separate line of navigation. This is quite a common pattern across various apps. For example, the official Twitter app's settings has the same usability pattern. Whether they do it the same way is another question, but the eventual outcome is the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the default edit more for the UITableView [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_4)

Or if you still want to do your custom toolbar, just use a normal ViewController (not UITableViewController) and add a UITableView and a the toolbar to it.

Comment: To have static cells you need to use UITableViewController. At least this proved true from both tests and information online alike. Do correct me if I'm mistaken though!

Comment: If you want static cells, then yes, you need a UITableViewController. So why don't you use the default editing mode?

Comment: Because the content will always be static. For maintainability and simplicity it's better to try and go with the flow with what Apple provide and what they suggest to do as that's what other developers maintaining the same codebase would be expecting. Thanks for your response though, it got me thinking :)